I created new table in QuestDB but can't see it in the web console
I created a table in QuestDB like this:
CREATE TABLE 'trades' (
    symbol SYMBOL,
    side SYMBOL,
    price DOUBLE,
    amount DOUBLE,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (timestamp) PARTITION BY DAY WAL;

and inserted data. But when I look at my web console, it doesn't appear.
But when I run a query like this:
SELECT * FROM trades LIMIT 100

it returns results fine, so the table is made, but I just can't see it.
How do I fix this?

This sounds like an issue present in some versions of QuestDB, where the metadata cache that feeds the UI has become desynced from the rest of the database metadata. This is likely the case if you refresh the web console and still don't see the table.
There are a couple of ways you can resolve this issue.

Restart the database. This is intrusive, but will cause a full refresh of the metadata, meaning that metadata queries that the web console uses will return the accurate data.

Use the following query (recommended only for 8.1.4 or higher versions):


SELECT hydrate_table_metadata('trades')
-- or
SELECT hydrate_table_metadata('*')

This query forces a refresh of the metadata for either the table specified, or for all tables. In 8.1.2, this should not be run if you are currently ingesting data, creating tables, or altering tables. In newer versions, this should be safe to run if absolutely necessary.
This issue is unlikely to occur in versions after 8.1.4.
If you make other metadata changes (rename table etc.) and they don't appear, the same steps should resolve those too.
